# How to stream desktop with flask

Tags: python, flask

I need to stream my desktop using flask but I'm confused. I saw here - https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/video-streaming-with-flask that I can "fool" flask to think I have a webcam and stream another images. I tried to get the desktop image using the gen(camera) method and made a few changes to the Camera class but I still get a blank screen and couldn't find a solution online.
My code:

```
import mss
import numpy

class Camera(object):
    def __init__(self):
        with mss.mss() as sct:
            # Part of the screen to capture
            monitor = {"top": 40, "left": 0, "width": 800, "height": 640}
        self.frames = sct.grab(monitor)

    def get_frame(self):
        return self.frames
```

```
from flask import Response
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template
import threading
import numpy
import time
import cv2
import mss
from camera import Camera


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

def gen(camera):
    while True:
        frame = camera.get_frame()
        yield (b'--frame\r\n'
               b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n')

@app.route('/video_feed')
def video_feed():
    return Response(gen(Camera()),
                    mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem arises from the fact that you are not encoding the raw data as JPEG.

The following implementation is based on excerpts from the code [here](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/flask-video-streaming-revisited). I've shortened the code a bit. Please take a look at the original to find out the missing parts. You should be able to put it together into a working completed variant.

```
import cv2
import mss
import numpy

import threading
import time

class Camera(object):
    thread = None
    frame = None
    last_access = 0

    def __init__(self):
        if Camera.thread is None:
            Camera.last_access = time.time()
            Camera.thread = threading.Thread(target=self._thread)
            Camera.thread.start()

            while self.get_frame() is None:
                time.sleep(0)

    def get_frame(self):
        '''Get the current frame.'''
        Camera.last_access = time.time()

        return Camera.frame

    @staticmethod
    def frames():
        '''Create a new frame every 2 seconds.'''
        monitor = {
            'top': 40,
            'left': 0,
            'width': 800,
            'height': 640
        }
        with mss.mss() as sct:
            while True:
                time.sleep(2)
                raw = sct.grab(monitor)
                # Use numpy and opencv to convert the data to JPEG. 
                img = cv2.imencode('.jpg', numpy.array(raw))[1].tobytes()
                yield(img)

    @classmethod
    def _thread(cls):
        '''As long as there is a connection and the thread is running, reassign the current frame.'''
        print('Starting camera thread.')
        frames_iter = cls.frames()
        for frame in frames_iter:
            Camera.frame = frame
            if time.time() - cls.last_access > 10:
                frames_iter.close()
                print('Stopping camera thread due to inactivity.')
                break
        cls.thread = None
```

In your example, only one image is created when the respective instance of the camera is initialized.
In the version above, a new picture is taken continuously every 2 seconds within a thread. This is then set as the current frame and streamed. If there is no connection to a client, the thread is terminated. The memory management has also been significantly revised.

Comment: it work but the frames does not refresh. do you know why?

Comment: @elad alkabets   -  I edited my answer. The code is now a little more extensive but is used in the same way.